# discord.py wait_for() bot responds to itself

Tags: python, discord.py

When I'm using wait_for() in my discord bot, sometimes it will immediately take in its own message as a response

```
def check_instant_return(m):
    return m.content

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return  

  if message.content.startswith('!example'):
    await message.channel.send("This is an example. Say 'y'")

    msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check_instant_return)

    # the issue is that sometimes msg.content = "This is an example. Say 'y" instead of the real user input

    if msg.content == "y":
      await message.channel.send("Alright")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return  

  if message.content.startswith('!example'):
    await message.channel.send("This is an example. Say 'y'")

    msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=lambda mess: mess.author == message.author and mess.channel == message.channel)

    # the issue is that sometimes msg.content = "This is an example. Say 'y" instead of the real user input

    if msg.content == "y":
      await message.channel.send("Alright")
```

Your check was useless, do it like this to check the author of your message.

Answer (score 0):

Using the check function of the wait_for, you can specify to only return if the author is different than the bot (`m.guild.me` returns the "me" (the bot) as user so you don't need to reference the client)

```
def check_instant_return(m):
    return m.author != m.guild.me and m.content
```

Source: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild%20me#discord.Guild.me

Answer (score -2):

Not sure why this is happening exactly, maybe a mistiming in the execution of commands on discord py's side. May I suggest, as a crude, temporary fix, you try adding a time.sleep before waiting for a message.

```
import time # top of the file

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  ...
  if message.content.startswith('!example'):
    await message.channel.send("This is an example. Say 'y'")

    time.sleep(0.5)

    msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check_instant_return)

    ...
```

Comment: This is not a robust way to solve the problem. In addition, using time.sleep() in an asynchronous function stops the whole program and this is not desirable.

Comment: @mdevolde Yes I know, I did say it is a crude, temporary fix for a reason. If they didn't need something fancy that would be an easy way to make it work.

Answer (score -3):

Tell the bot not to respond to itself(respond to anyone but itself)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).